# Why the parameter FUN in tapply is invalid combined with colwise

Tags: r, plyr, tapply

I usually use the combination of `colwise` and `tapply` to calculate grouped values in a data frame. However, I found unexpectedly that the parameter `FUN` in `tapply` cannot work correctly with `colwise` from `plyr`. The example is as follows:

Data:

`df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rep(1:2, each = 5), c = 2:11)`

Normal:

```
library(plyr)
colwise(tapply)(subset(df, select = c(a, c)), df$b, function(x){sum(x[x > 2])})
```

Above code is correct and can work normally. But if I add `FUN`, it will be wrong:

```
colwise(tapply)(subset(df, select = c(a, c)), df$b, FUN = function(x){sum(x[x > 2])})
```

Error is:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 

unused arguments (function (X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE) 
{
    FUN <- if (!is.null(FUN)) match.fun(FUN)
    if (!is.list(INDEX)) INDEX <- list(INDEX)
    nI <- length(INDEX)
    if (!nI) stop("'INDEX' is of length zero")
    namelist <- vector("list", nI)
    names(namelist) <- names(INDEX)
    extent <- integer(nI)
    nx <- length(X)
    one <- 1
    group <- rep.int(one, nx)
    ngroup <- one
    for (i in seq_along(INDEX)) {
        index <- as.factor(INDEX[[i]])
        if (length(index) != nx) stop("arguments must have same length")
        namelist[[i]] <- levels(index)
        extent[i] <- nlevels(index)
        group <- group + ngroup * (as.integer(index) - one)
        ngroup <- ngroup * nlevels(index)
    }
    if (is.null(FUN)) return(group)
    ans <- lapply(X = split(X, group), FUN = FUN, ...)
    index <- as.integer(names(ans))
    if (simplify && all(unlist(lapply(ans, length)) == 1)) {
        ansmat <- array(dim = extent, dimnames = namelist)
```

Could anyone explain the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `tapply`, but because you are loading `plyr` anyway, a more `plyr`-esque alternative would be: `sum_fun <- function(x) sum(x[x > 2])`; `ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(b), colwise(sum_fun))`. This also gives you an explicit 'b' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is that both `lapply` and `tapply` have an optional `FUN` argument. Note that `colwise(tapply)` is a function with the following line:

```
out <- do.call("lapply", c(list(filtered, .fun, ...), dots))
```

Let's go to this line with our debugger by writing

```
ct <- colwise(tapply); trace(ct, quote(browser()), at = 6)
```

and then running

```
ct(subset(df, select = c(a, c)), df$b, FUN = function(x){sum(x[x > 2])})
```

Now let's print `c(list(filtered, .fun, ...), dots)`. Notice that the first three (unnamed) arguments are now the dataframe, `tapply`, and `db$b`, with the `FUN` argument above coming in last. However, this argument is *named*. Since this is a `do.call` on `lapply`, instead of that argument becoming an optional parameter for `tapply`, it now becomes the main call on `lapply`! So what is happening is that you are turning this into:

```
lapply(subset(df, select = c(a, c)), function(x){sum(x[x > 2])}, tapply, df$b)
```

This, of course, makes no sense, and if you execute the above (still in your debugger) manually, you will get the exact same error you are getting. For a simple workaround, try:

```
tapply2 <- function(.FUN, ...) tapply(FUN = .FUN, ...)
colwise(tapply2)(subset(df, select = c(a, c)), df$b, .FUN = function(x){sum(x[x > 2])})
```

The `plyr` package should be checking for `...` arguments named `FUN` (or anything that can interfere with `lapply`'s job), but it doesn't seem the author included this. You can submit a pull request to the `plyr` package that implements any of the following workarounds:

Defines a local

```
.lapply <- function(`*X*`, `*FUN*`, ...) lapply(X = `*X*`, `*FUN*`, ...)
```

(minimizing interference further).

Checks `names(list(...))` within the `colwise(tapply)` function for `X` and `FUN` (can introduce problems if the author intended to prevent evaluation of promises until the child call).

Calls `do.call("lapply", ...)` explicitly with named `X` and `FUN`, so that you get the intended

```
formal argument "FUN" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Comment: Robert, thank you very much for your excellent step-by-step analysis.